# get absent ordered number in a single table

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I've got a single table (whitout any relation) like this in a SQLite3 database:

TAG_NUMBER   INT
  ITEM_NAME    VARCHAR

Each tag number is unique (primary key).
for example:

```
  TAG_NUMBER    ITEM_NAME
    1001          N2
    1002          NY
    1003          NR
    1005          YT
    1008          TE
```

I'd like to select all absent tag numbers:
for example:

```
Result-->
  TAG_NUMBER
   1004
   1006
   1007
```

Answer (score 1):

This requires SQLite 3.8.3 or later:

```
WITH RECURSIVE all_numbers(n)
AS (SELECT MIN(tag_number) FROM MyTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 1 FROM all_numbers
    WHERE n < (SELECT MAX(tag_number) FROM MyTable))
SELECT n FROM all_numbers
WHERE n NOT IN (SELECT tag_number FROM MyTable)
```